# AWS Quicksight - translate IDs to Names Using Foreign Key

Tags: amazon-web-services, foreign-keys, business-intelligence, amazon-quicksight, aws-documentdb

I have live data on DocumentDB
Provisioning data on Aurora (Postgres)

I would like to have both datasets on Quicksight for BI
The DocumentDB data uses internal IDs
The SQL holds the mapping to meaningful names

Is there a way to achieve such a thing?

I have a Glue job that extracts the data from the DocumentDB and outputs it as a JSON in S3
Regarding Aurora - Quicksight natively integrates

**Thanks**

Comment: Hi Amit, I am happy to help! Can you shed some more light on what your use case and goal is? Do you have the same data on both DocumentDB and Aurora?

Comment: Sure thanks
Let's explain by an example:
DocumentDB data: 
id - 1 
foo - bar
Aurora data:
id - 1
name - Joe
I wanna show a graph that correlates Joe to Bar

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have managed to achieve this after adding another data source to the same data set.
AWS then enables you to do a join between the data sources.